# How to include AAR in React Native Android?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In my React Native Android project, I want to use my own library which has a AAR file.
Can someone please guide on how to use the AAR file in my Android build.

Below are my configurations -

1. react-native - 0.69.1
2. gradle - 7.4.2
3. Android Studio Bumblebee - 2021.1.1 Patch 3
4. openjdk - "18.0.1.1" 2022-04-22

And I'm getting below error when creating build -

`Direct local .aar file dependencies are not supported when building an AAR. The resulting AAR would be broken because the classes and Android resources from any local .aar file dependencies would not be packaged in the resulting AAR. Previous versions of the Android Gradle Plugin produce broken AARs in this case too (despite not throwing this error). The following direct local .aar file dependencies of the :library-name project caused this error**`

Answer (score 2):

Copy the `library.aar` file into `react-native-module-name/android/app/libs`. Create the `libs` folder if it doesn't exist.

In `react-native-module-name/android/app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
 implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.aar"])
 implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'  // From node_modules
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in "react-native-module-name/android/app/build.gradle":

```
dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.aar"])
}
```

Copy the .aar files into "react-native-module-name/android/app/libs"

As this solution is not working
You can do this -

Remove the library from /libs and add it using -

```
File -> New -> New Module -> Import .JAR/.AAR
```

Create a new directory and put the following dependencies in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
 implementation project(":imported_aar_module")
}
```

Place the .aar file here to next directory, next to build.gradle file

Add the created Gradle project to the settings.gradle -

```
include(":pathToTheCreatedDirectory")
```

Include the file into the directory -

```
implementation project(":pathToTheCreatedDirectory", 
configuration = "default")
```

Comment: but I don't want to do it manually, I want that when I install my library, my react-native android module gets aar file from the libs of library

Comment: I'm getting same error as it is mentioned in my question

Comment: @ShubhamBisht, I have added the changes have a look

Comment: I need to confirm one thing, when you're using react-native-module-name, do you mean my React-Native Project or the library which I'm using in my React-Native Project?

Comment: Your react-native project

Comment: okay thanks, so can you please tell what do you exactly mean by "Create a new directory and put it in build.gradle"?

Comment: Sorry for a mistype, I meant, "Create new directory and put following content into the build.gradle within the new directory"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246431/discussion-between-shubham-bisht-and-rishav-raj).